Almost surely convergence of Bernoulli distribution ($\frac{1}{n}$)
So I have the following exercise: Let $X_n$ independent Bernoulli with parameter $\frac{1}{n}$, so
$$ P(X_n=1)=\dfrac{1}{n}, \quad P(X_n=0)=1-\dfrac{1}{n}.$$
Show that $X_n$ converges to $1$ almost surely. Since the random variables are independent, we can use the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, so
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n=1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n}=\infty,$$
then $P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}X_n=1)=1$. This is clear, BUT here is the question: we can do the same thing with $X_n=0$, or not (?), so $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n=0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\infty,$$ thus $P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}X_n=0)=1$??? Where is the mistake? Could someone please help?

For events $(E_n){n=1}^\infty$, the Borel Cantelli lemma tells us about $\lim\sup_n E_n$ (which is not to be confused with $\lim\sup_n X_n$). The $\lim\sup_n E_n$ is $$\bigcap{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty E_m.$$  This is also referred to as $E_n$ infinitely often (io). Your proof tell us that $X_n=1$ infinitely often almost surely. This is the same as saying $\lim\sup_n X_n=1$ almost surely. The second application of Borel Cantelli that you have says that $X_n=0$ infinitely often almost surely, which means $\lim\inf X_n=0$ almost surely.

Together, these tell you that if $A$ is the set of points such that $\lim_n X_n$ exists, $\mathbb{P}(A)=0$.

It's written that $X_n \to 1$ a.s. It's false. Indeed, $X_n \to 0$ in probability and hence  $X_n$ can't converge to $1$ a.s.
It looks like you imply that  $limsup X_n = 1$ a.s. Let us prove it correctly. It will allow to answer the original question a bit later.
Put $A_n = \{w: X_n(w) = 1 \}$. As $\sum_n P(A_n) = \infty$ by Borel-Cantelli lemma we have $P(limsup A_n) = 1$. Put $A = limsup A_n$. By definition $$limsup A_n = \cap_{N=1}^{\infty} \cup_{n = N}^{\infty}A_n.$$
We have $P(A) = 1$ and for all $w \in A$ we have $w \in (limsup A_n)$, i.e. for all $N$ there exists $n\ge N$ such that $w \in A_n$. In other words, if  $w \in A$ then for all $N$ there exists $n\ge N$ such that $X_n(w) = 1$. Hence $limsup X_n(w) \ge 1$ for all $w \in A$. But $P(A) = 1$. Thus $limsup X_n(w) \ge 1$ a.s. Note that $X_n \le 1$ and it follows that $limsup X_n(w) \le 1$ a.s. We proved that  $limsup X_n(w) =1$  a.s.
Now you may see where there was a mistake in your solution.
Your question was about changing $\{X_n = 0\}$ to $\{X_n  = 1\}$.  So consider $B_n = \{ w: X_n(w) = 0 \}$. Again we see that  $\sum_n P(B_n) = \infty$ and by Borel-Cantelli lemma we have $P(limsup B_n) = 1$. Put $B = limsup B_n$. We have $P(B) = 1$ and for all $w \in B$ we have $w \in (limsup B_n)$, i.e. for all $N$ there exists $n\ge N$ such that $w \in B_n$. In other words, if  $w \in B$ then for all $N$ there exists $n\ge N$ such that $X_n(w) = 0$. Hence $liminf X_n(w) \le 0$ for all $w \in B$. But $P(B) = 1$. Thus $liminf X_n(w) \le 0$ a.s. Note that $X_n \ge 0$ and it follows that $liminf X_n(w) \ge 0$ a.s. We proved that  $liminf X_n(w) =0$  a.s.
We see that if we consider $B_n = \{w: X_n(w) = 0 \}$ instead of $A_n = \{w: X_n(w) = 1 \}$ we will prove  that $liminf X_n(w) =0$ instead of $limsup X_n(w) =1$. And there's no contradiction. For example, the sequence $y_n = \frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}$ also satisfy the conditions $liminf y_n =0$ and $limsup y_n =1$.
